# expected expression before 'struct' on c

Tags: c, expected-condition

I tried to make a userdata where it's declared as a struct. I tried to use scanf, but everytime i tried to compile it always says "expected expression before 'userdata'.

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { char name[30]; char age[2]; char country[10]; char date[40];

} userdata;

int main() 
{ 
printf("Please input your name: \n");
scanf("%c", &userdata.name); 
printf("Please input your age: \n"); 
scanf("%c", &userdata.age); 
printf("Which country are you from: \n"); 
scanf("%c", &userdata.country); printf("Please tell me the date of your birth in number format (00 - 00 - 0000)\n"); 
scanf("%c", &userdata.date);


printf("Here's your userdata: \n");
printf("Name : %c\n", userdata.name);
printf("Age : %c\n", userdata.age);
printf("Country : %c\n", userdata.country);
printf("Date of birth : %c\n", userdata.date);

return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You created a type called `userdata` so now you need to declare an instance of the type to use it:

```
userdata u;
```

then you pass the address of the instance:

```
scanf("%c", &u.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the `typedef` keyword, you've declared `userdata` as a *type alias* for a `struct`.  It's not a variable name.

If you remove the `typedef` keyword, you'll declare a variable with that name.

Also, you need to use the `%s` format specifier to read and write strings.  The `%c` format specifier is used for single characters.  Also, since strings are terminated by a null byte, the `age` member of your struct should be longer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to a TYPE, not a variable. When you define `typedef`, you do not create a variable, you create an alias for the type.

Let's say you have the `int` type, but you don't like it being called `int`. Then you can do `typedef` and name the type int as you want:

```
typedef int MyType; // Create an alias for an int type
```

You do NOT create a variable of this type.

Your solution is to create a variable of `userdata` and set it to:

```
userdata data;
scanf("%s", &data.name);
```

In addition, as @dbush rightly noted, you need to use the `%s` specifier to read strings: the `%c` specifier is used only for single characters.